# MySql After Insert Trigger using a Select clause

Tags: mysql, triggers

The following query generates a random string of 20 characters:

```
SELECT LEFT(MD5(RAND()), 20);
```

My aim is to insert this into the token field of the users_address field when a new row is added.  I created the following trigger:

```
BEGIN       
    INSERT INTO users_address (token) VALUES (SELECT LEFT(MD5(RAND()), 20));
END
```

which returns the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual...".  If I replace the SELECT statement with an actual string, the trigger is created so the issue seems to be the SELECT.  What do I need to do to change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT` is not needed in `VALUES` Clause :

```
INSERT INTO users_address (token) VALUES (LEFT(MD5(RAND()), 20));
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/U8cyWMU5)